# Extract only Capital letters from a string - javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

```
 function onlyCapitalLetters (str)  

 { 

let newStr = "";

for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i ++) {
    if (str[i].includes("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ")) {
        newStr += str[i];
       
    }
}
return newStr;
}

onlyCapitalLetters("AMazing"); // should get AM
```

Hi, I'm trying to write a function, that will return a new string with only capital letters. When I try to run this function, I don't see any output. Please help!!!

Comment: The function you have written will require each letter to include the entire alphabet

Comment: Look into regex ```A-Z```

Comment: `str[i].includes("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ")` should be `"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".includes(str[i])`

Comment: `"Your String".match(/[A-Z]+/g).join("")`

Answer (score 8):

In practice, you would probably use a regex approach here:

```js
function onlyCapitalLetters (str) {
    return str.replace(/[^A-Z]+/g, "");
}

console.log(onlyCapitalLetters("AMazing")); // should get AM
```

Answer (score 2):

Include requires everything within to be included in the provided string. Use regex instead

```js
function onlyCapitalLetters (str) { 
  let newStr = "";

  for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
      if (str[i].match(/[A-Z]/)) {
          newStr += str[i];
      }
   }
   return newStr;
}


console.log(onlyCapitalLetters("AMazing")); // should get AM
```

You could one line this function like this

```js
const capital = (str) => str.split('').filter(a => a.match(/[A-Z]/)).join('')

console.log(capital("AMazinG"))
```

Answer (score 0):

The string of letters (`uppercaseLetters`) should include the current letter (`str[i]`), and not the other way around:

```js
function onlyCapitalLetters(str) {
  let newStr = "";
  
  const uppercaseLetters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

  for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    if (uppercaseLetters.includes(str[i])) {
      newStr += str[i];
    }
  }
  
  return newStr;
}

console.log(onlyCapitalLetters("AMazing")); // should get AM
```

A better option would be to use `String.match()` to find all uppercase letters. The match method returns an array of letters found, or `null` if none found, so we'll need to use an empty array as a fallback. Join the resulting array with an empty string.

```js
function onlyCapitalLetters(str) {
  return (str.match(/[A-Z]/g) || []).join('');
}

console.log(onlyCapitalLetters("AMazing")); // should get AM
```

Answer (score 0):

String.Includes() checks for all the characters in the string.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes

You can also use ASCII code for the Characters to verify if it is a capital letter.

```
function onlyCapitalLetters (str) { 
 let newStr = "";

    for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
      if (str[i].charCodeAt(0) >= 65 && str[i].charCodeAt(0) <= 90) {
          newStr += str[i];
       }
    }
  return newStr;
}

console.log(onlyCapitalLetters("AMazing"));
```